# Cannot see Win10 computer on network

Tags: windows-7, networking, windows-10, workgroup

I have a Workgroup with one Win10 and a number of Win7 computers, connected via a SMC 1016DT switch. The Win7 machines all see each other in Windows Explorer, but not the Win10. The Win10 can see all the others.

If I select Network Map in Control Panel, the Win10 is present, but double-clicking on it has no effect - for the others, it opens Explorer showing the shared folders.

Prior to a recent shutdown (due to power supply company maintenance) the Win10 was accessible by all the others.

How can I restore full access?

Comment: What network profile is the Win 10 box using? It may have reverted to the Public profile, but needs to be in the Private profile.

Answer (score 0):

Please ensure Windows 10 and Windows 7  are in same local network and workgroup.
What’s more, you could check your firewall settings.

I would suggest you to change to the following options for both the systems on the network in the advanced sharing settings **(Open Network & Sharing Center > Change Advanced Sharing settings):**

1.Turn on **Network Discovery**

2.Turn on **file and printer sharing**

3.Turn on sharing so anyone with network access can read and write files in the public folders

4.Turn off **password protected sharing**

If the above not work, please refer to the following link to setup home group again to have a try.
Home Group from start to finish
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17145/windows-homegroup-from-start-to-finish

If you just want share a folder, we can simply right-click the folder, then select "share with" to share this folder with everyone. Then we will be able to access this folder from other computers.

Have a nice day,

Peter

Comment: You should make sure to re-enable password protected sharing afterwards as it is a big security risk.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the above steps have been taken. Personally, for my home network, I have mine set to Private network and Password protected sharing On.

```
Make sure the Win 10 hard drive(s) or directories are still shared. If they are not shared, the Win 7 PC can see the Win 10 on the network, but not access it, and the Win 10 can access the Win 7's.
In Services (run, services.msc) make sure the following services are set to Auto: DNS Client, Functional Discovery Provider Host, Functional Discovery Resource Publication, SSDP Discovery, PnP Device Host. Auto means they will start automatically on startup, but not immediately, allowing the PC to boot faster.
Enable File Sharing Support for Client and Server: Control Panel > Programs > Programs and Features > Select Turn Windows features on or off > scroll down to SMB 1.0/CIFS File Sharing Support, Check the Client and Server checkboxes.
```

If the above have not worked, you can try:

```
Settings > System > About > Advanced System Settings > System Properties > Computer tab > Network ID. Select Business PC, My company uses a network w/o a domain.
Flush DNS Cache, open an elevated Command Prompt. At DOS (ex. C:\) type Ipconfig /flushdns.
Network Reset  - press Win + I to launch the Settings app, navigate to Network and Internet > Status and select Network reset. Or, from elevated Command Prompt:
```

netsh int ip reset.txt
netsh winsock reset
netsh advfirewall reset

```
Reinstall Network Adapter:

Device manager
Un-install network adapter
Restart and will be auto reinstalled.
```

Something in here has always fixed mine.